# SQL Query not working after using mycrypt

Tags: php

I am really new at PHP and I'm trying to add a value to data base using this code. I tried to echo all of the tags and everything worked except it doesn't show up in my data base. I had all that working as well till I added the encryption part. I already found that if I used `MCRYPT_RAND` instead of `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` it seemed to work better. Something tells me it might just be a simple error that I can't find. Any tips on how to find this error or answers appreciated.

```
<?php   
$account = "$_REQUEST[Account]";
$password = "$_REQUEST[Password]";
$pin = "$_REQUEST[Pin]";
$date = "$_REQUEST[Date]";
$username1 = "$_REQUEST[Username]";
$store1 = "$_REQUEST[Store]";
$category1 = "$_REQUEST[Category]";
$amount1 = "$_REQUEST[Amount]";
$bankaccount1 = "$_REQUEST[BankAccount]";
$notes1 = "$_REQUEST[Notes]";
$millisecond = "$_REQUEST[MilliSecond]";

    $sqlaccounts = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")
        or die (mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db("bumblebeesaccounts", $sqlaccounts);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `account` = '$account'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql, $sqlaccounts);

    $verify_account = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    $key = $verify_account['salt'];


    $username = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $username1, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $store = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $store1, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $category = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $category1, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $amount = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $amount1, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $bankaccount = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $bankaccount1, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $notes = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $notes1, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);



$sqlconnect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")
    or die (mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("bumblebeesbudgetapp", $sqlconnect);

$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO `bob` (`id`, `date`, `username`, `store`, `category`, `amount`, `bank account`, `notes`, `millisecond`, `receiptpicture`) 
    VALUES (NULL, '$date', '$username', '$store', '$category', '$amount', '$bankaccount', '$notes', '$millisecond', '')";

 mysql_query($sqlinsert, $sqlconnect);

echo $username;
echo mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $username, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

?>
```

Comment: see this `"$_REQUEST[Account]";` etc.? all your quotes are inversed. error.........reporting.

Comment: @Fred-ii- could you be a little more specific as in what you mean by inversed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it going now. The biggest change that i made is I base64 encrypted all the mcyrpt data.

```
$username = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $username1, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
$store = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $store1, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
$category = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $category1, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
$amount = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $amount1, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
$bankaccount = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $bankaccount1, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
$notes = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $notes1, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
```

Answer (score 0):

### Array Access

To get values from associative array like `$_REQUEST` you should change the using of qoutes from

```
...
$account = "$_ REQUEST[account]";
...
```

**to**

```
...
$account = $_REQUEST["account"];
...
```

### Insert statement

I think the column *id* is a primary key, isn't it? So it couldn't be *null*. If its an autoincrement column, you could leave the value:

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO `bob` (`date`, `username`, `store`, `category`, `amount`, `bank account`, `notes`, `millisecond`, `receiptpicture`) 
VALUES ('$date', '$username', '$store', '$category', '$amount', '$bankaccount', '$notes', '$millisecond', '')";
```

Comment: So something doesn't seem to want to work for me. I echoed out the $sqlinsert and manually inserted it in under the sql tab in phpmyadmin and got a huge error. Is it a possibility that this encryption ins't supported to insert with sql query because of special characters?

Comment: Could you post the error code, you get from phpmyadmin?